# Should I have to use canonical if I rewrite my URL?

Tags: canonical-url

For example if I have only one HTML page in my directory and if the link is `http://www.mydomain.com/my-landing-page.html` and, using *.htaccess* if I rewrite the URL to `http://www.mydomain.com/my-landing-page`, should I use canonical tag anywhere?

Or should I apply `noindex, nofollow` rule in *robots.txt* file for `http://www.mydomain.com/my-landing-page.html`?

I want my page look like `http://www.mydomain.com/my-landing-page` in search engines so, what should I do to `http://www.mydomain.com/my-landing-page.html`?

Comment: if it will remain that way (single file, static HTML page), you could as well create a folder named "my-landing-page" , and make your file "index.html". You can also define an 301-redirect to the folder, so you don't have to dealt with robots' or canonicals.

Answer (score 4):

If you 301-redirect from `/my-landing-page.html` to `/my-landing-page`, no one will ever get a 200 when visiting `/my-landing-page.html`. So you don’t need to do anything with this URL (besides redirecting). You shouldn’t block crawling of `/my-landing-page.html`, as otherwise bots may not notice that there is a redirect now.

You may use `canonical` for `/my-landing-page`. This could help in cases where URL variations show up (e.g., created by someone linking to your page) that still give 200 for your content.

Example (it depends on server configuration if this applies in your case): Someone might link to `/my-landing-page?we-sell-only-crap`. Thanks to the `canonical`, it’s now clear that this URL could be ignored.

```
 <!-- on /my-landing-page and variations  -->
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/my-landing-page" />
```